# UIToolbar position change after app enters foreground

Tags: iphone, position, uitoolbar, foreground

in my navigation based iPhone app I let users swipe the UIToolbar out of the way (I move the frame of self.navigationController.toolbar down by 23).

This works very well until the app is sent into background and reopened. When the app comes back to foreground the toolbar position is reset. This happens after UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is posted and after - (void)didBecomeActive …

At the moment I move the toolbar back to the lower position after entering foreground, but this results in kind of a flickering effect.

Could someone please push me in the right direction how I can prevent the toolbar position reset on entering foreground?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't manually change the frame of the toolbar. Call `-[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:animated:]` instead.

Comment: I don't want to hide the toolbar but still have it slightly visible to remind users that it's there.

Comment: Then you should manage the toolbar yourself, i.e. create a `UIToolbar` and add it to your view controller's view and leave the nav controller out of the game. As long as you let the nav controller manage the toolbar, you cannot rely on its not modifying its properties.